# Javascript: Key with array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to make an Object with key as a number and value as an array of objects. How can this be done in javascript?

I want to create an object that looks like this:

```
{Key: "1", value: [Object, Object, ...], key: "2", value: [Object, Object, ...], key:"N", value: [Object, Object, ...]}
```

How is this possible in javascript/typescript ?

I tried:

```
let myObj = {};
myObj["1"] = myObj["1"].push(Object)
```

Above code does not work.

Comment: 1) `.push` returns a number, I don't think you want to assign a number to `myObj["1"]` 2) You can't have the same key twice, so your wanted datastructure is impossible to achieve (and senseless), maybe you want an array of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` returns the new length of the array - so just call the function (doing nothing with the return value), making sure you've initialized the target array first:

```
let myObj = {};
myObj["1"] = myObj["1"] || [];
myObj["1"].push(Object);
```

You could also define a custom type:

```
type objectContainingObjects = { [key: string]: object[] }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, and it can be achieved in a number of ways. For instance, to achieve what you require with TypeScript, you could do the following:

```
/* Define a type describing the structure of your desired object (optional)
 */    
type CustomType = { [key: number]: Array<any> };

/* Create your object based on type definition with numbers as keys and array
   of objects as values */
const yourObject: CustomType = {
  1 : [1,2,3],
  2 : ['a','b','c'],
  3 : [ new Object(), new Object() ]
};
```

In JavaScript, the same can be achieved by omitting the typing:

```js
const yourObject = {
  1: [1, 2, 3],
  2: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  3: [new Object(), new Object()]
};

console.log(yourObject);

/* Adding more letters to value at key 2 */
yourObject[2].push('d', 'e', 'f');

console.log(yourObject);
```

Hope that helps!